# syntax input and output (Simple java)

Tags: java, syntax

**New to JAVA**

I have this input and this output/

```
import java.util.List;
```

input:`public class Solution{ List<Integer> lenght(List<Character> inputList){ body of method}}`

expected output: `[9,7,8]`

My syntax for processing it/

```
List<Integer> lenghts = new ArrayList();
```

it says **error can't find symbol** for the line above. My syntax is wrong (I think it's out dated, from an old tutorial)

Can someone please tell me the correct syntax for the the variable to the input and out put.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any `import` declarations at the top of your code?

Comment: yes/ import  java.util.List;

Comment: I hope that's actually `java.util.List` - small j for Java, capital L for List.  You'll also need `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: or simple `import java.util.*`

Comment: @emotionlessbananas Every time you use a `*` in an `import`, a kitten dies.  http://www.javadude.com/posts/20040522-import-on-demand-is-evil/

Comment: It didn't include 'java.util.ArrayList' I think you don't need it for this problem.

Comment: its good if he is not using any IDE to get the learning going,

Comment: You definitely need either `java.util.ArrayList` or `java.util.*`.  Please don't get into the habit of using the latter, as it can make your code break in unexpected ways.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Do I have to import these two libraries? It only gave me (.List) in the question.

Comment: Yes, for the third time.  You do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this thing List and ArrayList from java.util.*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

List<Integer> lenght(List<Character> inputList)
{
    List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    return li; 
}
```

Comment: Do I have to import these two libraries? It only gave me (.List) in the question.

Comment: java.util.*  or  java.util.ArrayList java.util.List both are one and the same the only differenece is that if you import java.util.* all collection which are present under this library you can call without any extra import or error

Comment: Got it Thank you!